# Need to move stored procedure into system stored procedure folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I created my stored procedure somehow I managed to place it within the stored procedures folder, however not inside the *system* stored procedures folder (the system SP folder exists within the stored procedures folder). How do I move it one level down into the system stored procedures folder?

EDIT: After reading the answers below I'm thinking that the problem is how I'm telling my C# program to access the stored procedure. I have this line of code that is throwing an exception, telling me that it cannot find it:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("<database_name>.dbo.<stored_procedure_name>.sql", conn);
```

If anyone can offer any help on how to call the stored procedure properly it would be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Wasn't aware that this was possible - this is the normal place for user stored procedures (I assume we are talking Microsoft SQL Server). System sprocs area is usually reserved for stuff that comes bundled with SQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You don't**, or at the least shouldn't.

This is for `system` stored procedures, which are built into the RDBMS and used for `system` functions, like renaming objects or checking users on the server.

Don't think of these as folders like in a file system - they are just organizing your objects based on existing meta-data (`Stored procedure` or `View`? `System` object or `User` object?)

You can conceivably mark it as a system object, but that's just a terrible idea.

Why do you want to obfuscate your procedure?  If you are creating it it's obviously a user procedure and not a system one.

Comment: +1 Although I've shown the method, I'd really rather he didn't do it either!

Comment: I think, then, maybe the problem is how I'm calling the stored procedure in my program. I have this written in C#: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AgentResourcesU01.dbo.sp_FactSheetUpdate.sql", conn);

Comment: @NealR You don't need the `.sql` in your procedure name - that's a file extension, and it's confusing `SQLCommand` because it's adding an extra part to the name

Comment: Yes...the `.sql` makes it a 4-part name of the form `<server>.<database>.<schema>.<object>`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm really not sure why you would need to do this, but you can:

```
exec sp_ms_marksystemobject myprocname
```

It's undocumented - so I you won't have any support if you try and use it, and it might be removed from a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can't "undo" this, you'll need to drop and recreate the procedure if you change your mind later.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @JNK's comment above.

Also, ensure that you've created the stored procedure under the schema you think you did. If you execute a statement like this:

```
create procedure foobar as ...
```

the stored procedure `foobar` gets created under your *default* schema, which is likely not `dbo`. You should **always** create and reference database objects with at least a 2-level, schema-qualified name:

```
create procedure dbo.foobar ...
create procedure some_schema.foobar ...
```

lest you shoot yourself in the foot. You should schema-qualify references as well. References like

```
select * from some_table
exec some_stored_procedure
```

rather than

```
select * from dbo.some_table
exec dbo.some_stored_procedure
```

are resolved by first probing for an object of the desired name and type under your *default* schema. If found, that is the object used to resolve the reference. If no such object is found, then a probe is made under the schema `dbo`.

Further, you should not generally give a stored procedure a name that begins with `sp_`: that further complicates (and slows down) resolution, throwing probes of the `master` database into the mix.